# Eliminating the impact of UnionFS on results when benchmarking inside Docker

Tags: linux, docker, filesystems, benchmarking, unionfs

I am trying to benchmark the overall system performance of running Docker using the Phoronix Test Suite 6.4.0 Milestone 2 running inside a fedora:23 image based container.

One thing that must be considered is, that Docker uses a proprietary UnionFS to store data. However, when running a real-world application (like Apache) inside Docker, the persistent data are usually stored on a dedicated folder on the host, running on a standard Linux filesystem like ext4, or in my case btrfs.

The solution I propose is to use the "[docker volume](https://docs.docker.com/engine/userguide/containers/dockervolumes/)" to mount a host directory into docker. The thing is I don't know which directories are to be used in the benchmarks and have to be mounted inside the Docker container.

The test Suite [pts/disk](http://openbenchmarking.org/suite/pts/disk) for example should definitely use docker volumes instead of UnionFS. It contains these tests.

```
pts/compress-gzip
pts/sqlite
pts/apache
pts/pgbench
pts/compilebench
pts/iozone
pts/dbench
pts/fs-mark
pts/fio
pts/tiobench
pts/postmark
pts/aio-stress
pts/unpack-linux
```

Which directories in the Docker container should be mounted from host (made docker volumes)? Is it even a good idea to use the docker volumes? Are there any other caveats to consider when benchmarking Docker?

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned in "[Mount a shared-storage volume as a data volume](https://docs.docker.com/engine/userguide/containers/dockervolumes/#mount-a-shared-storage-volume-as-a-data-volume)"

> In addition to mounting a host directory in your container, some [Docker volume plugins](https://docs.docker.com/engine/extend/plugins_volume/) allow you to provision and mount shared storage, such as iSCSI, NFS, or FC.

Since docker 1.9, this is done with [`docker volume create`](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/volume_create/) (and then you mount those volumes in their expected paths in the container)

That allows you to:

- make those volumes independent of the host
- still bypass UFS
- experiments with different [Docker volume plugins](https://docs.docker.com/engine/extend/plugins_volume/)
- compare [their performance benchmarks](https://stackoverflow.com/q/35137655/6309)

> Which directories in the Docker container should be mounted from host

Any folder which include persistent data, and/or has an high volume of IO operations.

Comment: Just to note, the answer to the question "why use a data volume plugin like flicker" instead of just "Docker data volume" is "Unlike a Docker data volume which is tied to a single server, a Flocker data volume, called a dataset, is portable and can be used with any container in your cluster." Afaik if I sacrifice portability, Docker data volume is functionally equivalend, and probably even faster than any Docker volume plugin, right?

Comment: @Slazer I agree. I just prefer using docker volume create since docker 1.9 as, plugin or not, it keeps volumes more visible, instead of being hidden being a container which exists just to be started (never run) and mounted by other containers.

Comment: Could you please advise me, looking at the tests I am going to run (generally disk I/O intensive tasks using real-world applications), which folders are the best candidates to being mounted from host (as a docker volume or docker volume plugin)? I have not programmed the test, so I do not see any easy way to guess which folders are in use. The tests are being run as root inside a Docker container.

Comment: @Slazer It really depends on the application being run. Hence my last general-worded sentence in my answer. Try running your test without volume first, to establish a baseline, then introduce volumes.

Comment: I guess the best way to know is to confine them one by one inside the home directory (by SELinux perhaps) and see what happens. I suspect them trying to use something like `/tmp` and maybe `/var` or `/usr`. At least Apache and SQLite could perhaps get by solely with my home directory...